# Show or hide component if user is logged in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have setup register and login page... with nodejs express jwt, and token is saved in cookies. My goal is to check if user is signed in and then show or hide element in the navbar. Thus far this is what i came with. My problem with this solution is that i have to refresh the browser because i have to make get requests for conditional render to work. Please help.

```
function Navbar() {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const[isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
       checkLogin()
    }, []);


    const checkLogin = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/token', {withCredentials: true});
            setIsLoggedIn(true)
        } catch (e) {
            setIsLoggedIn(false)
            console.log(e)
        }


    }


    const Logout = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/logout', {withCredentials: true});
            navigate("/");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    const showDrawer = () => {
        setVisible(true);
    };

    const onClose = () => {
        setVisible(false);
    };


    return (
        <div className="menu">
            <Link to='/'>

                <div className="logo"/>
            </Link>
            {!isLoggedIn? (

                <Menu theme="dark" mode='horizontal' disabledOverflow='true'>
                    <Menu.Item><Link to='/login'>Log In</Link></Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item><Link to='signup'>Sign Up</Link></Menu.Item>
                </Menu>
            ) : (

                <Button className='logout' onClick={Logout}>Log out</Button>
            )}

            <Button className="barsMenu" type="primary" onClick={visible ? onClose : showDrawer}>
                <span className="barsBtn"/>
            </Button>
            <Drawer
                placement="bottom"
                closable={false}
                onClose={onClose}
                visible={visible}
                closeIcon
            >
                <Link to='/login'>
                    <Button onClick={onClose}>Log in</Button>
                </Link>
                <Link to='/signup'>
                    <Button onClick={onClose}>Sign up</Button>
                </Link>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Update:
this is my login component

```
const LoginForm = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onFinish = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', {
                email: email,
                password: password
            },{withCredentials:true})
            navigate('/profile')
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                setMsg(error.response.data.msg)
                console.log(error)

            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='login-form-landing'>
            <div className="login-form-inner">
                <Form
                    name="normal_login"
                    className="login-form"
                    initialValues={{
                        remember: true,
                    }}
                    onFinish={onFinish}
                >
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Button className='facebook-button'>Continue with Facebook</Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Button className='google-button'>Continue with Google</Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                        name="email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        rules={[
                            {
                                required: true,
                                message: 'Please input your email!',
                            },
                        ]}
                    >
                        <Input prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon"/>} placeholder="email"/>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                        name="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        rules={[
                            {
                                required: true,
                                message: 'Please input your Password!',
                            },
                        ]}
                    >
                        <Input
                            prefix={<LockOutlined className="site-form-item-icon"/>}
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                        />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item name="remember" valuePropName="checked" noStyle>
                            <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                        </Form.Item>

                        <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">
                            Forgot password
                        </a>
                    </Form.Item>

                    <Form.Item>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button form-submit">
                            Log in
                        </Button>
                        <div className="or-link">
                            <span>Or</span>
                            <Link to='/signup'>register now!</Link>
                        </div>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginForm
```

Comment: Are you saying you need for `checkLogin` to run more often than when the `Navbar` component mounts? The code is conditionally rendering on `isLoggedIn` state, and that's being updated and should trigger a rerender. Why do you need to reload the browser?

Comment: Well when logged in i want that login and signup disappear, and logout shows up... at this point a get that only when i refresh browser. So after log in i have to refresh browser in order to logout show.

Comment: What happens after a user logs in? Where does that happen? Should you pass the `setIsLoggedIn` function so the state here in the navbar can be updated after authentication?

Comment: i have updated my code... you can see my login form... other part is happening in the nodejs backend...

Comment: maybe my useEffect is not right?

Comment: I think your login component needs to be passed a callback to update the state in the navbar. The `useEffect` hook should probably use the `isLoggedIn` state as a dependency. The answer below is likely a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isAuth, token etc states can be stored in Cookie or local/session storage and state management should be done with Context API so when the page is refreshed the states are not lost

```
const LoginContext = createContext({isAuth:false,token : "", 
                                    setAuth: () => {}})

const LoginProvider = ({child}) => {
   const [isAuth,setAuth] = useState(localStorage.getItem("isAuth") || false)
   const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"))
   useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem("isAuth",isAuth)
   },[isAuth])
   return (
        <LoginContext.Provider value={{isAuth,token,setAuth}}>
             {child}
        </LoginContext.Provider>
      )
    }
```

While logging in

```
const {isAuth, setAuth}= useContext(LoginContext)
const login = async () => {
   var result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/token', {withCredentials: true});
   var { data} = result.data;
   setAuth(data != null) //or conditional state

}
const logout = async () => {
   await axios.get('logout')
   setAuth(false) //or conditional state
}
```

LoginContext children can access context values

```
<LoginContextProvider>
 <Navbar />
</LoginContextProvider>
```

can use isAuth in navbar or other component

```
var {isAuth} = useContext(LoginContext)
```

Comment: I have managed to setup context and it works, but when i refresh the page, isAuth is set  to true again and i dont know why?

Comment: i have figured it out... i dont know why but after logout, isAuth is set string false instead of boolean...

Comment: you can do it as `localStorage.getItem("isAuth") == 'true'`